# Custom order for multiple joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query in SQL Server that replicates following figure:

[image]

I want the result of first left join (order_defect & ncdef) to be left join with third table (filter) and again the result of these three left join with last one (nsdic).

Each of these tables are huge, so I'm trying to find most efficient way to do it because i have limited space and I get "out of memory" error... any suggestion for an efficient query?

If I do:

```
Select * 
from A
left join B on a.id = B.id
left join C on a.id = c.id
```

it's joining A and B first and then A and C...but I want the result of  "A & B" to be join with "C".

Basically my question is how to use a result of one join, to join with another table.

Thank you

Comment: Most database engines attempt to optimize queries, so unless you've inspected the _execution plan_ you don't really know how the query is being performed. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: i remember that for next time thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dificult to help you without the tables design and fields|columns, keys, ...

But I'll considerate:

1 - Primary keys fields, and how to relation the tables

2 - How to add left joins with "filters", or how to reduce the number of results

3 - Evaluate if it'll be better to use Sub-querys

Plus: Try the query with TOP 100 <--- to make test.

And remember: sometimes it's imposible to optimizate querys because of the hardware limits, like the RAM, in those case you have to show the data in sections.

Comment: thanks for suggestions but my main question is how to use the resualt of one join to do another join in same query, do you know how to do it? because if i do "A left join B  left join c" it's left joining A with B and then left joining A with C righ? but I want tyhe result of A & B to be join with C

Comment: basically my question is how to use a result of one join, to join with another table. 

its easy:

select
 c.id
 ,c.colum1
 ,c.colum2
 ,c.colum3
 ,c.colum4
 ,t3.colum1
from
(
select
 t1.id as id
 ,t1.colum1 as colum1
 ,t1.colum2 as colum2
 ,t2.column1 as colum3
 ,t2.colum2 as colum4
from table1 t1
 left join table2 t2
 on t1.id = t2.id
) as c
 left join table3 t3
 on c.id = t3.id

Answer (score 1):

```
 select
    c.id
    ,c.colum1
    ,c.colum2
    ,c.colum3
    ,c.colum4
    ,t3.colum1
from
(
select
    t1.id as id
    ,t1.colum1 as colum1
    ,t1.colum2 as colum2
    ,t2.column1 as colum3
    ,t2.colum2 as colum4
from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
) as c
    left join table3 t3
    on c.id = t3.id
```